# Express router + WebSocketServer - sending message on POST

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

This is what I've got so far, and I'm trying to find a solution so that:

- The connection is always kept alive, so I can handle status updates
- I can send a websocket message to a client with data from the POST request

ws [api here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md)

```
 router.post('/', function (req, res) {
// Need to send ws.send() with post data
})


wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('r : %s', message);
  });
  // ws is only defined under this callback as an object of type ws
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use event like this :

```
//Create an event
var event = require('events').EventEmitter();

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
   // fire an event
   event.emit('homePage')
})

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
     console.log('r : %s', message);
    });

    // listen the event
    event.on('homePage', function(){
        ws.emit('someEvent');
    });
});
```

Comment: `event` is undefined when I try this

Answer (score 1):

I got an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

I think I could misunderstand or missing something that could be obvious for anyone else. The error comes when the emit call is requested:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
   // fire an event
   event.emit('homePage') <----------- HERE
})
```

I'm adding at the beginning:

```
var event = require('events').EventEmitter();
```

**UPDATE!**
I solved it changing the line where requires events by this 2:

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

After that it's working.

Comment: I solved adding this at the begining...
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();